# CodeColorer: Allow Some Symbols in Java Language

Tags: plugins

I have a quick question about CodeColorer plugin. How can I allow less then (<) and greater then (>) signs in java code. I am asking this because they are used in Generics but they are being stripped away when I use lang = java, so I am forced to use lang = html for now.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks for taking time to read this.

**Update:**

ok, the issue is resolved now.

The thing was that anything resembling html, like , was stripped by WordPress for all roles less then admin. I added this code to make it work for contributor,

$role = get_role( 'contributor' );
$role->add_cap( 'unfiltered_html' );

This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the plugins FAQ:

```
I see &lt; instead of < (or other HTML entities like >, &, ") in my code.
```

You should use `[cc escaped="true"]` or `[cce]` in the visual editor when inserting code into the post.

Comment: Doesn't work. It may be a WP issue as when I write [cce lang="java"]<test>[/cc] or [cc escaped="true" lang="java"]<test>[/cc], only [cce lang="java"][/cc] remains after saving the post.